# Explanation for why some multi-mapped reads in BWA-MEM have MapQ of 0 while other multi-mapped reads do not

Tags: bioinformatics

I used BWA-MEM from BWA v0.7.17 to map RNA reads to a reference database made of seven cyanobacterial CDS files joined with cat. When I did this following the command below:

```
bwa mem -k 10 -aM -t 24 Merged_reference3 InputR1.fastq.gz InputR2.fastq.gz > Out.sam
```

I noticed that the resulting sam file raised a few questions. Below is an example of 7 lines from the resulting SAM file:

```
A00521:369:HWY3MDSX3:4:1112:2202:35869  81  fig|165597.4.peg.5438|CwatDRAFT_1423|VBICroWat128338_5438|photosystem   604 9   62M26S  lcl|NC_009091.1_cds_WP_002805533.1_241  585 0   GTTGCTGGTGTATTCGGTGGTTCTTTATTCTCTGCAATGCACGGTTCATTAGTAACTTCTTCACTAATCCGTGAAACAACAGAGTCTG    FFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF:F:FFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF    NM:i:5  MD:Z:20A11C2T11C8C5 MC:Z:31M57S AS:i:37 XS:i:31
A00521:369:HWY3MDSX3:4:1112:2202:35869  337 fig|203124.6.peg.233|Tery_0183|VBITriEry99848_0233| 614 0   44M44H  lcl|NC_009091.1_cds_WP_002805533.1_241  585 0   *   *   NM:i:3  MD:Z:2A27A0G12  MC:Z:31M57H AS:i:31
A00521:369:HWY3MDSX3:4:1112:2202:35869  337 fig|203124.6.peg.231|Tery_0182|VBITriEry99848_0231| 504 0   44M44H  lcl|NC_009091.1_cds_WP_002805533.1_241  585 0   *   *   NM:i:3  MD:Z:2A27A0G12  MC:Z:31M57H AS:i:31
A00521:369:HWY3MDSX3:4:1112:2202:35869  161 lcl|NC_009091.1_cds_WP_002805533.1_241  585 0   31M57S  fig|165597.4.peg.5438|CwatDRAFT_1423|VBICroWat128338_5438|photosystem   604 0   GCACCCATTCCACATGGCTGGTGTTGCTGGTGTATTCGGTGGTTCTTTATTCTCTGCAATGCACGGTTCATTAGTAACTTCTTCACTA    FFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF:F:FFF::,FFFFFFFFFF:FFF:FFFFFF:FFFFFFFFFFFF:FFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF:FFFF    NM:i:0  MD:Z:31 MC:Z:62M26S AS:i:31 XS:i:31 SA:Z:fig|203124.6.peg.231|Tery_0182|VBITriEry99848_0231|,507,+,25S41M22S,0,2;
A00521:369:HWY3MDSX3:4:1112:2202:35869  417 fig|203124.6.peg.231|Tery_0182|VBITriEry99848_0231| 507 0   25H41M22H   fig|165597.4.peg.5438|CwatDRAFT_1423|VBICroWat128338_5438|photosystem   604 0   GCTGGTGTATTCGGTGGTTCTTTATTCTCTGCAATGCACGG   :,FFFFFFFFFF:FFF:FFFFFF:FFFFFFFFFFFF:FFFF   NM:i:2  MD:Z:27A0G12    MC:Z:62M26H AS:i:31 XS:i:20 SA:Z:lcl|NC_009091.1_cds_WP_002805533.1_241,585,+,31M57S,0,0;
A00521:369:HWY3MDSX3:4:1112:2202:35869  417 fig|203124.6.peg.233|Tery_0183|VBITriEry99848_0233| 591 0   15M1I3M2D47M22H fig|165597.4.peg.5438|CwatDRAFT_1423|VBICroWat128338_5438|photosystem   604 0   *   *   NM:i:7  MD:Z:18^AG2A2A27A0G12   MC:Z:62M26H AS:i:31
A00521:369:HWY3MDSX3:4:1112:2202:35869  417 fig|203124.6.peg.6041|Tery_4763|VBITriEry99848_6041|    591 0   15M1I3M2D47M22H fig|165597.4.peg.5438|CwatDRAFT_1423|VBICroWat128338_5438|photosystem   604 0   *   *   NM:i:7  MD:Z:18^AA5A11T15A0G12  MC:Z:62M26H AS:i:30
```

The main question I have is how the MapQ score (column 5) is 9 for the primary alignment for the first sequence in the pair but 0 for everything other thing. Clearly the first sequence in the pair has multiple alignments so shouldn't it also be 0?

I found some resources for how to calculate MapQ below:
https://bioinformatics.stackexchange.com/questions/2417/meaning-of-bwa-mem-mapq-scores
https://genome.cshlp.org/content/suppl/2008/09/26/gr.078212.108.DC1/maq-supp.pdf

According to these articles, MapQ is calculated as below

MapQ = 10/log10⋅[log4⋅(S1−S2)−lognsub]

and

MapQ =  (−c log p2) − (−c log p1) − c log n2

where S1 and S2 are the alignment scores for the best hit and second best hit,
n sub is the number of suboptimal alignments,
c is 3.434,
p2 is the probability that the second best alignment maps to more than one place,
p1 is the probability that the best alignment maps to more than one place, and
n2 is the number of second-best alignments.

The second part of my question is that I would like to calculate MapQ based on the values in the SAM lines above but am having trouble reproducing the calculated results. Using the AS and XS flags, I know S1 = 37, S2 = 32, and n sub = 2, but when I calculate MapQ with the first expression I get the following:

[10/log 10][log4(6)-log(2)] = 3.311 not 9.

For the second expression I set p2 = 0.000794, p1 = 0.000199, and n2 = 2 and return - 3.09.

It would be great to get thoughts on if these are the correct expressions for MapQ in BWA-MEM as well as if I am making a mistake in the order of operations or have defined any of the variables wrongly.